# How to count of cmd.exe process with a specific title?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

[image: dividing product proc commands]

I'd like to count cmd.exe process with a title `dividing product proc`. I'm able to count cmd.exe like below:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%# in ('qprocess^|find /i /c /n "cmd.exe"') do (
    set number=%%#
)
```

But this code counts every `cmd.exe`. Is there a way to count cmd.exe with its title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following batch file demonstrates how this task can be done with a batch file using the command [tasklist](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) (SS64 documentation) documented also by Microsoft on [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) page containing a link to [tasklist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist) documentation.

```
@echo off
set "ProcessCount=0"
for /F "skip=3 delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq dividing product proc" 2^>nul') do set /A ProcessCount+=1
echo Number of cmd.exe processes with window title "dividing product proc": %ProcessCount%
echo/
pause
```

The first three lines of output of **TASKLIST** are skipped by **FOR** because of `skip=3`. Run in a command prompt window `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq dividing product proc"` to see why the first three lines of output of **TASKLIST** are not of interest for counting `cmd.exe` processes with window title `dividing product proc`. `delims=` is used to disable line splitting behavior by specifying an empty list of delimiters to process the lines a very little bit faster.

It is also possible to use **TASKLIST** option `/NH` (No Header) to get the list of processes output without a header as suggested by [sst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4561332/sst) (thanks) which makes usage of `skip=3` unnecessary.

```
@echo off
set "ProcessCount=0"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq dividing product proc" /NH 2^>nul') do set /A ProcessCount+=1
echo Number of cmd.exe processes with window title "dividing product proc": %ProcessCount%
echo/
pause
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `tasklist /?`

Comment: An alternative to `skip=3` is to ask `tasklist` to omit the column header by `/NH` switch.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It's what I'm looking for!!